# Importing python modules from a subfolder

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-import

I would like to import modules from within the following folder structure by referencing the sub-module `app`.

```
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── getters
│       │   ├── company_1.py
│       │   └── company_2.py
│       ├── parsers
│       │   ├── company_1.py
│       │   └── company_2.py
│       └── writers
│           ├── company_1.py
│           └── company_2.py
```

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
# src/app/writers/company_1.py

import app.parsers.company_1 as parser_1


def write_data(event, context):
    ...
```

but I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. I don't understand why this shouldn't work.

**NOTE**

Why am I including the seemingly redundant sub-folder `app`? The side story here is that the functions `writers/company_*.py` will be implemented as Lambda functions on AWS, and in order to get all the necessary dependencies, I need to upload the contents of the src folder to AWS but need to have a top-level folder with a known name so that I can use it for absolute imports.  Without `app` the contents of src are uploaded to a folder with an autogenerated name which I cannot reference.

I first tried relative imports, but received an `attempted relative import with no known parent package` error, so now I am going for absolute imports, inspo from [here](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/06a64ba80cf3fe886053f0ca6d375bc0).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try having in `__init__.py` inside your app folder ?

```
module
|
|--module
|  |
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--module.py
```

Comment: Yes, there is an __init__.py inside the app folder. I was hoping that would do the trick, but no dice.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this in the code ,

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "source"))
```

Just replace `source` with the folder where you have saved your modules.
In this case replace `source` with `app`

Comment: So, I would put this inside `src/app/writers/company_1.py`, before the import? It's a little hard on they eye, but I suppose that's the way it's got to be?